# Two domains one site .htaccess rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site with two similar domain names. The problem is that Google is indexing this as two different sites.

How do I point the one domain to another?

**foo.se/example** should go to **bar.se/example**

I have tried this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.se
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bar.se/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

But **foo.se/example** only leads to **bar.se** (without sub directory)

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule with `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `$1`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.se$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://bar.se%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Seems logical, but it doesn't work. Maybe because it's a joomla installation with seo component? foo.se/example now leads to bar.se/index.php

Comment: Is it is Joomla then make sure this above rule is very first rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Perfect! It did work when I added the line just below RewriteEngine On! Thanks! :)